# How can I format entry_date when using AJW export?

Tags: solspace-freeform, export, entry-date, date-format

I'm exporting freeform entries with AJW export, and have no idea how to format the entry_date field when exported as .csv

AJW export documentation doesn't appear to exist, besides a sample EE tag you can use. Has anyone else formatted entry_date when exporting entries as a .csv?

Here is my code (changed filename):

```
{exp:ajw_export 
    sql="SELECT entry_date, form_field_1, form_field_2, form_field_3, form_field_4 FROM exp_freeform_form_entries_1" 
    format="csv" 
    delimiter=","
    filename="filename.csv"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(entry_date), '%Y-%m-%d') AS post_date

Answer (score 0):

Wow! This little gem just saved my bloody head. All my date comparisons were failing due to the UNIXTIME. I was trying to use DATE_FORMAT() and it just kept giving me errors, but this solved that. THANK YOU!! Like 3+ years later.